# Windows equivalent of GreaseKit?

Tags: safari, userscripts

When running Safari on a Mac, you can install [GreaseKit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/), which allows you to install UserScripts.

Is there an equivalent for the Windows version of Safari?

Comment: @Jeremy: That's what I need it for... testing a UserScript I wrote.

Comment: And I have a harder time trying to figure out people who use IE :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an equivalent for Safari called **NinjaKit**, as well as other alternatives:

- [NinjaKit](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit)
- [Greasemonkey Emulation](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105153)
- [Cross-Browser Userscripting](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Cross-browser_userscripting)